# Excel VBA: "xxxxx.xlsm may contain features that are not compatible with excel macro-enabled workbook..."

Tags: vba, excel

I have an xlsm file that I open upon launching Excel, which I update once in a while with some new code. It works fine.

Since a couple of weeks ago, when saving this file I get

*my_utils.xlsm may contain features that are not compatible with excel macro-enabled workbook do you want to keep the workbook in this format?*

Is there any way to know which code or feature is causing the warning?

I can sequentially remove portions of code, preferably reverting the sequence of additions/modifications. In my case, it might be not so easy, so I am looking for a spec of the possible causes, so perhaps I can spot it right away.

PS: the warning did not appear after any change in Excel versions or file format (xlsx -> xlsm). There was only code addition/updating.

**EDIT**:
I obtained a minimalistic version of my xlsm that still gives the warning, with only one dummy `Public Function` in it.
After commenting that Function and saving, the warning goes away. After uncommenting the Function and saving, the warning does not come back (it went away forever).

[image]

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Thanks. I will try cleaning it up, and sending it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I have a cleaned-up version. Are you ok with me sending it? How?

Comment: Hi. I am out of town and will be back on the 6th. Leave a comment after 6th and I will return to this question :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Are you ok to get the sample?

Answer (score 0):

First of all that doesn't have to be your code...

You should try to save it as Binary .xlsb - It works as good as .xlsm and it is even faster and smaller. No difference in compatibility with macros.( I always use this file type)

If you don't get a pop up - problem fixed, if you still receive this massage, check if you added some external objects, or formats... If you add code which is not compatible, macro simply won't work...

Comment: `and it is even faster...` Only when working with large files else there is hardly any difference :)

Comment: True, somehow I just assumed that his file is big... ;)

Comment: @Data.life - I will try and come back. So by saving in a different format the warning may go away? Does that mean that the information contained is different (not only in a different format)?

Comment: Hey, honestly this popup usually appears when you use older file types of Excel. Usually it should contain some Summary with the description of the problem. Is there any?  [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg132972(v=office.14).aspx#odc_xl14_ta_ExcelCompatibilityChecker_AdditionalResources

Comment: @Data.life - As said, I am quite sure that the only thing that changed was adding code. Please check the updated question with an image of the generic dialog. Clicking on help just leads to the main help menu.

Answer (score 0):

As to the specific question

*Is there any way to know which code or feature is causing the warning?*,

I wouldn't know.
But I managed to eliminate the warning.

Traverse each module, select all code and comment it.
Save the file. The warning disappeared.
Then traverse each module again, uncommment all code.
The warning is gone forever, and code is the same.
There was no need to work with Forms or Class Modules.

Mystery...